# Is there a PowerShell Script that can Compare CSVs Side by Side?

Tags: powershell

I have two CSVs with data populated from running a query. I intend to compare them both to see what are the differences using `Compare-Object` cmdlet.

The CSV files looks like this:

CSV1

```
TableName        ColumnName
------------------------------
Container        ContainerName
Container        Location
Container        ReceivedDate
Container        TopMark
```

CSV2

```
TableName        ColumnName
------------------------------
Container        Containername
Container        Location
Container        DateReceived
Container        BackMark
```

Right now, what I'm using is the `Compare-Object` cmdlet which is readily available in PowerShell. It runs great and I'm getting the results I wanted. However, the results might be difficult to understand for people who do not know how to read results generated by `Compare-Object` cmdlet. I've tried to simplify the results by comparing each of the properties but my end users somehow still don't understand the results. I even changed the SideIndicator to note if an object is existing on the Reference or Difference copy.

```
$compareResult = (Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $file1 -DifferenceObject $file2 -Property TableName, ColumnName |
    ForEach-Object {
        $_.SideIndicator = $_.SideIndicator -replace '=>',$onlyD -replace '<=',$onlsyG
        $_
    })
```

What they wanted to see is something like this:

```
LeftSideInputObject        RightSideInputObject
-----------------------------------------------
Container,ContainerName    Container,ContainerName
Container,Location         Container,Location
Container,ReceivedDate
                           ContainerDateReceived
Container,TopMark
                           Container,BackMark
```

Is there by any chance that I can do this in PowerShell? Thank you!

Comment: Comparing CSVs is very much related to the structure of the CSV. I think you need to implement your own compare based on the structure of the files you are targeting.

Comment: Extending on @Alex comment: can you add two csv samples to your question (as code blocks -not as pictures-, see also: [mvce])?

Comment: Hi @iRon, I've editted the question as requested. Thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Select-Object` to create a customized object.

```
Compare-Object $file1 $file2 -Property TableName,ColumnName -IncludeEqual | Select-Object @(
    @{ n = "Left";   e = { if ($_.SideIndicator -in "==","<=") { $_.TableName,$_.ColumnName -join "," } } }
    @{ n = "Right";  e = { if ($_.SideIndicator -in "==","=>") { $_.TableName,$_.ColumnName -join "," } } }
)
```

Comment: This worked extremely well, @rokumaru. Thank you very much for the help. This is the answer I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Check this:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Collections

#-----------------------------------------------------
class comparerClass {   # class for result object
#-----------------------------------------------------

    comparerClass(
        [string]$leftSide,
        [string]$rightSide
    )
    {
        $this.leftSide  = $leftSide
        $this.rightSide = $rightSide
    }

    [string]$leftSide = ''
    [string]$rightSide = ''
}

# Collections: File1, File2 and result list

[System.Collections.Generic.List[string]]$contentFile1 = @()
[System.Collections.Generic.List[string]]$contentFile2 = @()
[System.Collections.Generic.List[comparerClass]]$comparerList= @()

# Files to process

$pathFile1  = 'D:\csv1.txt'
$pathFile2  = 'D:\csv2.txt'

# read files to generic lists

$contentFile1.AddRange( [System.IO.File]::ReadAllLines( $pathFile1 ) )
$contentFile2.AddRange( [System.IO.File]::ReadAllLines( $pathFile2 ) )

# pointer for generic lists

$ptrFile1 = 0
$ptrFile2 = 0

# process lists, mainloop

while( $ptrFile1 -lt $contentFile1.Count ) {

    # equal, easy is this
    if( $contentFile1[ $ptrFile1 ] -eq $contentFile2[ $ptrFile2 ] ) {
        $tmpComparer =  New-Object comparerClass -ArgumentList $contentFile1[ $ptrFile1 ], $contentFile2[ $ptrFile2 ]
        $comparerList.Add( $tmpComparer )
        $ptrFile1++
        $ptrFile2++
    }
    else {    # not equal, check if entry list 1 comes later in list 2
        $ptr   = $ptrFile2 + 1
        $found = $false
        while( $ptr -lt $contentFile2.Count ) {
            if( $contentFile1[ $ptrFile1 ] -eq $contentFile2[ $ptr ] ) {      # entry found later in list2!
                for( $i = $ptrFile2; $i -lt $ptr; $i++ ) {
                    $tmpComparer =  New-Object comparerClass -ArgumentList '', $contentFile2[ $i ] 
                    $comparerList.Add( $tmpComparer )
                }
                $ptrFile2 = $ptr + 1
                $found    = $true
                $ptrFile1++
                break
            }
            $ptr++
        }
        if( !$found ) {     # entry not found, this entry only exists in list1
            $tmpComparer =  New-Object comparerClass -ArgumentList $contentFile1[ $ptrFile1 ], ''
            $comparerList.Add( $tmpComparer )
            $ptrFile1++
        }
    }

}

# process remaining entries in list2
while( $ptrFile2 -lt $contentFile2.Count ) {
    $tmpComparer =  New-Object comparerClass -ArgumentList '', $contentFile2[ $ptrFile2 ] 
    $comparerList.Add( $tmpComparer )
    $ptrFile2++
}

# show result
$comparerList
```

Comment: Your answer worked as well, @f6a4. However, I flagged the response as the correct answer as it needs minimal changes on my script. Thank you too!